# Debug symbols not included in gcc-compiled C++

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, clang, cython

I am building a module in C++ to be used in Python. My flow is three steps: I compile the individual C++ sources into objects, create a library, and then run a setup.py script to compile the .pyx->.cpp->.so, while referring to the library I just created.

I know I can just do everything in one step with the Cython setup.py, and that is what I used to do. The reason for splitting it into multiple steps is I'd like the C++ code to evolve on its own, in which case I would just use the compiled library in Cython/python.

So this flow works fine, when there are no bugs. The issue is I am trying to find the source of a segfault, so I'd like to get the debugging symbols so that I can run with gdb (which I installed on OSX 10.14, it was a pain but it worked).

I have a makefile, which does the following.

### Step 1: Compile individual C++ source files

All the files are compiled with the bare minimum flags, but -g is there:

```
gcc -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++14 -c -g -O0 -I ./csrc -o /Users/colinww/system-model/build/data_buffer.o csrc/data_buffer.cpp
```

I think even here there is a problem: when I do nm -pa data_buffer.o, I see no debug symbols. Furthermore, I get:

```
(base) cmac-2:system-model colinww$ dsymutil build/data_buffer.o
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
```

### Step 2: Compile cython sources

The makefile has the line

```
cd $(CSRC_DIR) && CC=$(CC) CXX=$(CXX) python3 setup_csrc.py build_ext --build-lib $(BUILD)
```

The relevant parts of setup.py are

```
....
....
....
compile_args = ['-stdlib=libc++', '-std=c++14', '-O0', '-g']
link_args = ['-stdlib=libc++', '-g']
....
....
....
      Extension("circbuf",
                ["circbuf.pyx"],
                language="c++",
                libraries=["cpysim"],
                include_dirs = ['../build'],
                library_dirs=['../build'],
                extra_compile_args=compile_args,
                extra_link_args=link_args),
....
....
....
ext = cythonize(extensions,
                gdb_debug=True,
                compiler_directives={'language_level': '3'})

setup(ext_modules=ext,
      cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
      include_dirs=[np.get_include()])
```

When this is run, it generates a bunch of compilation/linking commands like

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/colinww/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/colinww/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I. -I../build -I/Users/colinww/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/colinww/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c circbuf.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/circbuf.o -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++14 -O0 -g
```

and

```
g++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/colinww/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -L/Users/colinww/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/circbuf.o -L../build -lcpysim -o /Users/colinww/system-model/build/circbuf.cpython-37m-darwin.so -stdlib=libc++ -g
```

In both commands, the -g flag is present.

### Step 3: Run debugger

Finally, I run my program with gdb

```
(base) cmac-2:sim colinww$ gdb python3
(gdb) run system_sim.py
```

It dumps out a ton of stuff related to system files (seems unrelated) and finally runs my program, and when it segfaults:

```
Thread 2 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000a4585469e in cpysim::DataBuffer<double>::Write(long, long, double) () from /Users/colinww/system-model/build/circbuf.cpython-37m-darwin.so
(gdb) info local
No symbol table info available.
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000a4585469e in cpysim::DataBuffer<double>::Write(long, long, double) () from /Users/colinww/system-model/build/circbuf.cpython-37m-darwin.so
#1  0x0000000a458d6276 in cpysim::ChannelFilter::Filter(long, long, long) () from /Users/colinww/system-model/build/chfilt.cpython-37m-darwin.so
#2  0x0000000a458b0d29 in __pyx_pf_6chfilt_6ChFilt_4filter(__pyx_obj_6chfilt_ChFilt*, long, long, long) () from /Users/colinww/system-model/build/chfilt.cpython-37m-darwin.so
#3  0x0000000a458b0144 in __pyx_pw_6chfilt_6ChFilt_5filter(_object*, _object*, _object*) () from /Users/colinww/system-model/build/chfilt.cpython-37m-darwin.so
#4  0x000000010002f1b8 in _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords ()
#5  0x000000010003be64 in _PyMethodDescr_FastCallKeywords ()
```

As I mentioned above, I think the problem starts in the initial compilation step. This has nothing to do with cython, I'm just calling gcc from the command line, passing the -g flag.

```
(base) cmac-2:system-model colinww$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

### UPDATE

I removed the gcc tag and changed it to clang. So I guess now I'm confused, if Apple will alias gcc to clang, doesn't that imply that in "that mode" it should behave like gcc (and, implied, someone made sure it was so).

### UPDATE 2

So, I never could get the debug symbols to appear in the debugger, and had to resort to lots of interesting if-printf statements, but the problem was due to an index variable becoming undefined. So thanks for all the suggestions, but the problem is more or less resolved (until next time). Thanks!

Comment: It might be a good idea to use `g++` instead of `gcc` for `c++` compilation.

Comment: @TarickWelling Doesn't really matter on Mac; both `gcc` and `g++` are just aliases for Clang anyway (with C++ support ready to go; look at the configure options above)

Comment: This is not GCC; it is Clang. Mac aliases one to the other (ugh!). You should retag and also change your build command to reduce confusion.

Comment: Thanks, just tried it and it didn't change anything. I was under the impression that gcc, g++, all link to clang under the hood? The binaries produced seem to be identical.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Changed it, thanks for clarifying. I was in the middle of writing my original response when you replied, didn't see it until after.

Comment: Pardon my confusion, I'm no mac user myself so I didn't know about this intricacy. Sounds like a dangerous thing though to map a `c++` compiler to a `c` one. Other oses don't map `gcc` to clang as far as I know and that would be a bit weird as `gcc` is older than `clang`.

Comment: @TarickWelling I agree it is a bit confusing. You can install the real gcc through homebrew and then have clang and gcc live side-by-side on your machine. That's what I do.

Comment: @TarickWelling Bear in mind that gcc, g++ and clang are all just front-ends so there's nothing "dangerous" regarding C vs C++. However, mapping GCC commands to a completely different toolchain is indeed pretty ludicrous. I think it was Apple's way to standardise everybody's build chain without requiring people to retrain from the long-held habit of typing gcc or g++. Youch.

Comment: I just brewed gcc-9, and changed my makefile to use that compiler. I know I'm using actual gcc this time, because it complained about my clang flags -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -stdlib=libc++. But, still I don't see any debug symbols in any of my object files. I feel like I must be doing something so stupid.

Comment: Well, performance benchmarks of the working portions of code are ~15% faster?? I thought gcc was supposed to be slower...

Comment: _"I thought gcc was supposed to be slower..."_ ?

Comment: _"So I guess now I'm confused, if Apple will alias gcc to clang, doesn't that imply that in "that mode" it should behave like gcc (and, implied, someone made sure it was so)."_ No it's just Apple being silly. Forget about GCC here

Comment: Do you have any large memory allocations which are being allocated when you enter your non python code? And maybe it helps to compile python with debug symbols or use a version with explicit support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macOS linker doesn't link debug information into the final binary the way linkers usually do on other Unixen. Rather it leaves the debug information in the .o files and writes a "debug map" into the binary that tells the debugger how to find and link up the debug info read from the .o files.  The debug map is stripped when you strip your binary.

So you have to make sure that you don't move or delete your .o files after the final link, and that you don't strip the binary you are debugging before debugging it.

You can check for the presence of the debug map by doing:

```
$ nm -ap <PATH_TO_BINARY> | grep OSO
```

You should see output like:

000000005d152f51 - 03 0001   OSO /Path/To/Build/Folder/SomeFile.o

If you don't see that the executable probably got stripped.  If the .o file is no around then somebody cleaned your build folder earlier than they should have.

I also don't know if gdb knows how to read the debug map on macOS.  If the debug map entries and the .o files are present, you might try lldb and see if that can find the debug info.  If it can, then this is likely a gdb-on-macOS problem.  If the OSO's and the .o files are all present, then something I can't guess went wrong, and it might be worth filing a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: I'm using gcc-9 built from homebrew, and I am following your exact process, to inspect the object prior to linking. I don't get any symbols with OSO. What's weird is now I'm debugging the C++ python module by attaching lldb to the running python process, and it seems to work (the source code is present in the debugger). So I guess it's functional, just doesn't behave the way everyone is telling me it should.

Comment: The OSO symbols aren't in the object files, they get inserted by the linker into the final linked image.

Comment: @Jim Ingham What does "OSO" stand for?

Comment: That was so long ago - we started using them ~15 years ago to handle DWARF left in .o files on Darwin - that I can't remember now whether we made these up or if we repurposed them from the original Sun stab implementation.  Anyway, you need to know the source file for the compile unit - which is the N_SO stab, and it's companion object file, thus N_OSO.  I have a feeling the N_SO was there already and we added N_OSO, but that was a long time ago!